# jQuery sortable: How to properly post element id array?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

question:

I am working with jQuery sortable.
I used this tutorial:
http://www.xmech.net/programming/jquery-ui-sortable-tutorial/

Now this gives me a string like:

```
ID[]=2&ID[]=3&ID[]=4&ID[]=1
```

or even worse, when I call the id's IDa_1, IDb_2, IDc_3, IDd_4 it gives me

```
IDb[]=2&IDc[]=3&IDd[]=4&IDa[]=1
```

I find this format maximum horrible and unuseful...
I want just pages : ["IDb_2", "IDc_3", "IDd_4", "IDa_1"]
and have the order of the element in the array index.

To rectify this, I did:

```
var xxx =  { pages: $(this).sortable('toArray') };
alert(JSON.stringify(xxx));
```

This is my home controller:

```
public string SaveSortable(string pages)
{
    string strPages = Request.Params["pages"];

    Console.WriteLine(pages);
    return pages;
}


    public ActionResult Sortable()
    {
        return View();
    } // End Action Sortable
```

The problem is, both "pages" and strPages is always null...
It gets into the right controller though...
What am I doing wrong ?

This is my .cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        html {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;}
        body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%;}
        input{margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>



    <style type="text/css" media="all">

         .menu li 
         {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
            width: 150px;
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-ui/1_8_21/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js")"></script>  


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        Date.prototype.getTicksUTC = function () {
            return Date.parse(this.toUTCString()) + this.getUTCMilliseconds();
        } // End Function getTicksUTC


        var tickURL = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery/SlickGrid/images/tick.png")';


        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$('#menu-pages').sortable();
            $("#menu-pages").sortable({
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    alert("posting");

                    //var ElementsOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                    var ElementsOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');//.toString();
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(ElementsOrder));

                    var xxx =  { pages: $(this).sortable('toArray') };
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(xxx));
                    //document.writeln("<h1>"+ JSON.stringify(xxx) + "</h1>");


                    // $.post("@Url.Action("SaveSortable", "Home")?no_cache=" + new Date().getTicksUTC(), { pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize') });
                    // $.post("@Url.Action("SaveSortable", "Home")?no_cache=" + new Date().getTicksUTC(), { pages: $('#menu-pages').sortable('serialize', { key: 'id' }) });

                    $.post("@Url.Action("SaveSortable", "Home")?no_cache=" + new Date().getTicksUTC(), { pages: $(this).sortable('toArray') });

                }
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu-pages">
        <li id="ID_1">Home</li>
        <li id="ID_2">Blog</li>
        <li id="ID_3">About</li>
        <li id="ID_4">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use a JSON request:

```
$('#menu-pages').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveSortable", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ pages: $(this).sortable('toArray') }),
            success: function(result) {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSortable(string[] pages)
{
    // pages will contain what you need => a list of ids
    ...
}
```

For the record, here's how the JSON request POST payload will look like:

```
{"pages":["ID_2","ID_3","ID_1","ID_4"]}
```

Comment: Do I HAVE TO use $.ajax ? Is it not possible with $.post ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use `$.ajax`, as it allows you to set the proper request Content-Type header to `application/json`, thing that you cannot do wit `$.post`.